# Running multiple git commands in one line with aliases

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I have 2 different "scripts" for git that I have 2 aliases for, and I'd like to run them both in one line.

The first alias, let's call it `printStatus` looks like this:

```
pushd . && clear && cd /c/dev/erdm-desktop && find . -name .git -type d -execdir pwd \; -execdir git status \; -prune && popd
```

It traverses all my git directories and prints out their status. But in addition to this, I want it to delete all the branches it finds. The command to that is `clean`, and looks like this:

```
git fetch -p origin && git branch -r --merged origin/develop | grep -v develop | grep -v \"release/\" | grep \"origin/\" | cut -d \"/\" -f 2- | xargs -i git push origin :{}
```

Both these work great on their own, but I can't seem to find a way to combine them. Can you call an alias from an alias? Can someone show me how to execute these 2 commands?

Comment: Those are shell aliases, correct ? are you using bash ?

Comment: I'm using Git Bash, yes.

Comment: Yes, you can call an alias from an alias

Comment: just create a function and add this your .bashrc and call your alias together `runalias () {
    alias1
    alias 2
  
}`

Comment: The problem with that is the first alias is recursive. I need to call the second alias within it, if that makes sense.

Comment: this is what did alias ll='ls-l'  and second alias jatin='ll >1.txt' 

then run `jatin`. Here jatin alaias uses ll alias, ll alias is being called from within jatin alias this is how you can replicate

Comment: Note that you cannot call an alias from `find .. -execdir command_here` -- that needs to be an executable command from the PATH. You might want to transition to executable scripts instead of aliases.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra : Shouldn't there be a semicolon between the two alias invocations in your example?

Comment: @CNDyson:  What do you mean by **to combine**? Something like `printStatus && clean`?

Comment: Yep, that's what I want. Except `printStatus` is recursive, and I don't know how to fit `clean` inside of the call.

Comment: @user1934428 instead of semicolon add it like a function in .bashrc

Comment: Of course this would be even better; or, for most flexibility,  write it as a standalone script. It's just that the OP seems to prefer aliases for whatever reason....

Comment: Ok, I'll take a script too. I thought an alias would be cleaner, but my ultimate goal is to recurse through my git directories and delete all local branches. What would that script look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `find ... -exec <command>`, `<command>` is not executed with the same shell as your inital shell, and it probably isn't aware of your aliases -- which you probably defined in your `.bashrc`.

If you have some incentive to really keep these commands as *bash aliases*, you can intruct `-exec` to run the commands you type using bash and loading your `.bashrc` :

```
# I may be missing details on how to escape correctly the elements :
find ... -exec bash -i -c clean \;
```

But an easier way is :

- write the sequence of actions in a *script* which is placed on your *PATH* :

```
# say you have your one liner in a script named 'clean', in '$HOME/bin' :
$ cat ~/bin/clean
#!/bin/bash
git fetch -p origin && git branch -r --merged origin/develop | ...

# that script should be executable :
$ git chmod u+x ~/bin/clean
# place $HOME/bin in your path (you can set this in your .bashrc) :
$ PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH

# 'clean' is now an executable which can be called by any other process :
$ zsh -c clean
$ find ... -exec clean
```

---

You may want to turn these one liners into git aliases, which will have a similar effect : `git` will always load your root config file (`~/.gitconfig`) when you run it :

```
# 'clean' is already a git command, so we'll use another alias :
$ git config --global alias.clean-repo '! git fetch -p origin && git branch -r ...'

# with this alias on, you can invoke it using :
$ git clean-repo

# this will also work from within 'find ... -exec <command>' :
$ find ... -exec git clean-repo
```

Comment: I ended up doing a variant of your answer, so I'll accept it. Thanks!